# pg_search_scope with self-referencing association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I have a self-referencing association:

```
class EventAttendee < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :initial_attendee, class_name: "EventAttendee", foreign_key: :initial_attendee_id
```

And using the pg_search gem I am trying to write a pg_search_scope to match against the event_attendee records and also the (self-associated) initial_attendee records (which are also actually event_attendee records). As far as I can tell, this should work:

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
    against: [:last_name, :first_name, :email],
    associated_against: {initial_attendee: [:last_name, :first_name, :email]}
```

But it doesn't -- it just returns the matching regular event_attendee records, but not any that match the associated initial_attendee records. Any ideas about why this isn't working and how I can get this to work? I actually have another search scope for a different standard belongs_to association in that same model which is working great. Is it something about the self-referential association?

Comment: Would be good to mention that a special gem is involved. Besides, you almost certainly need some kind of recursive query. Using PostgreSQL you can find the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE . Make sure to get the desired output in PostgreSQL before proceeding in Rails.

Comment: BTW: Reading the documentation of the PgSearch-Gem it says: "PgSearch builds named scopes that take advantage of PostgreSQL's full text search" - so I don't think that recursive queries are within the scope of this gem. So you either find another gem or proceed on your own :-D